# Where do I implement a converter in a camel component?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

Me and my colleague want to develop a **camel component** that not only takes care of the connectivity, but also **converts the standard xml and / or json formats into the necessary message format** for the target system.

Where should we implement that? In our opinion, we have two options:

1. Implementation directly in the **producer**
2. Implementation in a **converter class** which is used by the producer

Is there a standard or is it up to the developer himself how many helper classes he defines for his camel component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no enforced standard. Both options are valid and it depends a bit. The type converters are more flexible and allows you to do these convertions elsewhere than only when sending via the producer.

For example some components that support industry standards like HL7 provide type converters to offer that kind of flexibility.

And some other components where these data formats of the target system are very special/specific do not use type converters but do it directly in the producer.

Comment: That's the answer I was expecting, and it encourages me to go on like this. Thank you for the fast answer Claus